# Slider with process of loading track

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uislider

I have to do AVPlayer with UISlider. But there is a problem. I know how to make a slider gray and blue, but I don't know how to add on slider this light blue line, which shows progress of loading track [image]

Code for default left line:

```
self.tintColor = .blue
self.maximumTrackTintColor = .gray
self.minimumValue = minValue
self.value = currentValue
self.maximumValue = maxValue
```

How to control light blue line? How to add it?

Comment: What you want isn't supported by UISlider. See the [following search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+uislider+buffer) for possible solutions.

Comment: Default UISlider doesn't support. Make your custom one, it's really easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of me UISlider doesn't have any property that can resolve your problem.
I've achieved the same `UISlider` by making some customisation.

Just place your `UISlider` immediately on top of your `UIProgressView` and make them the same size in Interface Builder place.

On a `UISlider` the background horizontal line is called the track, the trick is to make it invisible. We do this with a transparent PNG and the UISlider methods `setMinimumTrackImage()` and `setMaximumTrackImage()`.